# Orfeo ToolBox is not working properly in QGIS 3?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, qgis-3, python-toolbox, plugins

I have installed QGIS 3 and Orfeo ToolBox in it. The toolbox is not working properly.

Is there any way to use it in ArcGIS 10 with Python 2.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the instructions in how to [Add Orfeo Toolbox to QGIS 3.X](https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/add-orfeo-toolbox-to-qgis-3-x/), it should work properly.

There are two main steps you need to do:

- Download the Orfeo library Download the matching version for your
  operational system in the following address:
  https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeo-toolbox-6-6-is-out/
- Download the Orfeo plugin files from gitlab

You need to do some configurations and it should work.